# Set properties in child UserControl of a current View with ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a main View called `MainContentView.xaml` in wich I have set the DataContext to a ViewModel called `MainContentViewModel.cs`. Here I can update the values that appear in the UI, just as a normal MVVM would work.
It looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="namespace:MyProject.View.Home.MainContentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:UserTools="clr-namespace:MyProject.View.Tools"
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel.Home"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:MainContentViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <!-- Normal objects -->
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Text="Im a label" />
            <TextBox />
        </StackPanel>
        <!-- My Custom Object -->
        <UserTools:MyCustomUserControl x:Name="myUserControl" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my `MainContentViewModel.cs` looks like this:

```
public class MainContentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string myLabel = "";
    public string MyLabel {
        get { return this.myLabel; }
        set {
            this.myLabel = value;
            OnPropertyChangedEvent("MyLabel");
        }
    }

    public MainContentViewModel() {
        MyLabel = string.Format("my label text");
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChangedEvent(string _propertyName) {
        var _handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(_handler != null) { _handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_propertyName)); }
    }
}
```

Now I want to set some properties in the `MyCustomUserControl.xaml` through it's own `MyCustomUserControlViewModel.cs`.
My `MyCustomUserControl.xaml` looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.View.Tools.MyCustomUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel.Tools"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:MyCustomUserControlViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Label Content="{Binding myCustomLabel}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my `MyCustomUserControlViewModel.cs` looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomUserControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string myCustomLabel = "";
    public string MyCustomLabel {
        get { return this.myCustomLabel; }
        set {
            this.myCustomLabel = value;
            OnPropertyChangedEvent("MyCustomLabel");
        }
    }

    public MyCustomUserControlViewModel() {
        MyCustomLabel = string.Format("my custom label text");
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChangedEvent(string _propertyName) {
        var _handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(_handler != null) { _handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_propertyName)); }
    }
}
```

Now I want to, from the `MainContentViewModel.cs`, update the `MyCustomLabel` property on the `MyUserCustomUserControl.xaml`, and I suppose I have to do it through the `MyCustomUserControlViewModel.cs` so I can keep the MVVM pattern.

I've tried something like this:
In the `MainContentViewModel.cs`

```
private MyCustomUserControlViewModel _viewModel = new MyCustomUserControlViewModel ();
(...)
public MainContentViewModel() {
    (...)
    _viewModel.SetMyCustomLabel("my new custom label text");
}
```

And in `MyCustomUserControlViewModel.cs`

```
public void SetMyCustomLabel(string _text) {
    MyCustomLabel = _text;
}
```

But this does not work. I'm guessing it's because I'm instantiating another `MyCustomUserControlViewModel.cs` object.

So, how can I do this?

**UPDATED AND WORKING** (Thank you Sheridan)
I picked up one of Sheridan's solutions and ended up with this working solution. In my `MainContentView.xaml`:

```
(...)
<UserTools:MyCustomUserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

In my `MainContentViewModel.cs`:

```
private MyCustomUserControlViewModel childViewModel = new MyCustomUserControlViewModel();
public MyCustomUserControlViewModel ChildViewModel {
    get { return childViewModel; }
    private set { childViewModel = value; OnPropertyChangedEvent("ChildViewModel"); }
}
```

And then I can do this:

```
public MainContentViewModel() {
    (...)
    ChildViewModel.SetMyCustomLabel("my new custom label text");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parent view model had access to the actual child view model instance that is used (which it probably doesn't because of the way that you instantiate your child view model), then you could have simply done this:

```
public MainContentViewModel() {
    (...)
    _viewModel.CustomLabel  = "my new custom label text";
}
```

**1.**

One solution would be to remove the child view model from the child view to the parent view model and then to display the child view using a `ContentControl` and a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MyCustomUserControlViewModel}">
    <Views:MyCustomUserControlView />
</DataTemplate>

...
```

In MainContentViewModel:

```
public MyCustomUserControlViewModel ChildViewModel
{
    get { return childViewModel; }
    private set { childViewModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ChildViewModel"); }
}

...

<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <!-- Normal objects -->
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Text="Im a label" />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- My Custom Object -->
    <ContentControl x:Name="myUserControl" Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

Doing this would enable you to call the property simply, as shown in my first example.

**2.**

One alternative would be to move the property to the parent view model and bind to it directly from the child `UserControl`:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Label Content="{Binding DataContext.myCustomLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={x:Type Views:MainContentView}}}" />
</Grid>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

**3.**

Ok, I've just had another idea... you *could* add another property into the parent view model and data bind to the child view model like this maybe:

```
<UserTools:MyCustomUserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel, 
Mode=OneWayToSource}" x:Name="myUserControl" />
```

This is just a guess, but it *might* be able to hook onto the child view model like this... then you could do this in the parent view model:

```
if (ChildViewModel != null) ChildViewModel.CustomLabel = "my new custom label text";
```

**4.**

Actually... I've just had another idea. You could do bind from a property in your parent view model through to the `UserControl` if you add a `DependencyProperty` to it:

```
<UserTools:MyCustomUserControl CustomLabel="{Binding CustomLabelInParentViewModel}" 
x:Name="myUserControl" />
```

You could simply remove the property from the child view model in this case.

Comment: When you're reffering the `<Views:MyCustom... />` inside the DataTemplate, are you referring to the same as `x:Type ViewModels:MyCustom...`?
Also, I can't create the ChildViewModel in the `MainContentViewModel` like you said.
Regarding your last solution, I just gave the example of a label in the `UserControl`, the object is far more complex, that's why it's a different `UserControl`, and it is used in several places. That's what I gathered from what you said, at least.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error which I've now corrected. The `Views` XML Namespace prefix is the prefix for your Views. The `DataTemplate` just sets an instance of your view to be displayed when an instance of your view model is found in the UI.

Comment: I figured that's what you were saying. So basically I create a `DataTemplate` of a child View with the DataType of my child ViewModel. Is the `ChildViewModel` declaration in the `MainContentViewModel` correct?  And I suppose you have to bind it in the View, like so: `<ContentControl x:Name="myUserControl" Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}" />`, so it does not return an error.

Comment: Yep, sorry again, the `Binding` keyword was missing from my example of the `ContentControl`, but it sounds like you've got the picture.

Comment: I'm trying your new suggestions, however the last one does not seem appropriate for scenario since I have quite a few properties to change. One thing that I still can't get right, in the `MainContentViewModel` how do you get the child ViewModel? The way you posted is not working and I'm having trouble getting the object.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry... I was just being lazy... it was meant to have a private setter but I couldn't be bothered to type it all out. Don't forget to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on it to.

Comment: Thank you Sheridan, I finally managed to get it working. I'm gonna update my first post with my solution, but I'll mark your post as the answer since it was thanks to you that I got there. Btw the `Mode=OneWayToSource` has to be `Mode=OneWay` otherwise it does not work.

Comment: Good, I'm glad I could help. However, I'm guessing that you are now instantiating your `ChildViewModel` in the parent view model, so a `Mode=OneWay` would be suitable, but in that particular suggestion, I was bearing in mind that you instantiated the `ChildViewModel` in the child view model, so I believe that in that case, the `Mode=OneWayToSource` is correct.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. In that case how do you declare the `ChildViewModel` in the child view model and how do you get it in the parent view model?

Comment: The idea was that because you already declared the `ChildViewModel` in the child view, then we should be able to bind *from* the `ChildViewModel` *to* the parent view model so that you could access it. However, if you have added the `DataTemplate` now, then I'd advise that you use that method because it is better. Maybe I shouldn't have given you so many different options? :)

Comment: Options aren't always bad, and in this case I'm lucky enough to choose the one that suits me best, and if someone else ends up here, they have more to choose from too. I'm not using the `DataTemplate`, so I'm guessing it's not the same solution you were talking about. Without using the `DataTemplate`, how can I declare the `ChildViewModel` in the child view model and then get it in the parent view model?

Comment: I've never tried this, so it *might* not work, but just declare the `MyCustomUserControlViewModel` in the `UserControl.DataContext` as you were before. The `Binding` I gave you for that was supposed to bind directly to whatever is set as the `DataContext`, so it *should* work... just add that `ChildViewModel` property into the parent view model to 'receive' the value. Just to confirm, we're talking about option 3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42975/discussion-between-josemartins-grupoma-and-sheridan)

Comment: Sorry, but you're going to have to continue on your own... I'm just about to go out. Just experiment a bit and you should get there ok.

Comment: No problem Sheridan. I was just trying to figure if it could be done. I'll update my post with my implemented solution. Thank you again for the help.